# changing the description of a FB custom tab URL post

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, feed, fb.ui

When pasting a link from a custom tab on the wall, i noticed that the description is taken from the info tab instead of the custom tab. I would like to change the description to something that relates to the custom tab. Does anybody know how to do this?

The desciption under the posted link is not from this source: http://www.facebook.com/commerzbankcareer?sk=app_265085363536247 but form this http://www.facebook.com/commerzbankcareer?sk=info

i tried to add the FB.ui feed dialog in the Facebook SDK in the PHP file of the custom tab, however this did not work:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>  <script type="text/javascript">    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {     FB.init({appId: '265085363536247', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});   window.setTimeout(function() {     FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();   }, 250);   };   (function() {     var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;     e.src = document.location.protocol +       '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);   }());function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://www.facebook.com/commerzbankcareer?sk=app_265085363536247',
      picture: '',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
```